# Cannot view image in PostScript File

Tags: postscript

This is my first time working with PostScript files. There is an image that I would like to view but when I open it with GSView a window comes up with the following error:

```
Error: /nocurrentpoint in --currentpoint--
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1983   1   3   %oparray_pop   1982   1   3   %oparray_pop   1966   1   3   %oparray_pop   1852   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1198/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:81/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory

--- Begin offending input ---
%**************************
%****** Start BMP PS ******
%**************************
gsave
currentpoint ~y$pos exch def ~x$pos exch def
~DeviceGray setcolorspace
x$pos y$pos 92 87 rectclip
x$pos y$pos translate
96 88 scale 
<<
~ImageType 1
~Width 800 ~Height 735
~BitsPerComponent 1
~Decode [ 0 1 ]
~ImageMatrix [ 800 0 0 735 0 0 ]
~DataSource currentfile ~ASCIIHexDecode filter
>>
image
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000
00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0
0000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
--- End offending input ---
file offset = 1024
gsapi_run_string_continue returns -101
```

When I open it on my Mac with Preview, it also gives me an error that it is not able to open because it isn't able to convert to PDF.

How  can I view the image?

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the actual PostScript program its hard to say exactly what the problem is, however nocurrentpoint is quite a specific error, it means you haven't specified an initial location before attempting to draw something.

But I notice that the 'offending input' begins with `gsave currentpoint`, that will also give you an error if you haven't already specified an initial point.

Try putting `0 0 moveto` earlier in the program (you might also try `100 100 moveto`, the PostScript co-ordinate system has 0,0 at the bottom left).

I imagine the 'distiller' application on the Mac is encountering the same error when interpreting the PostScript, which is why it can't convert it to a PDF file.